# Xcode 5.0: Apple where is Add Build rule gone?

Tags: xcode5, build-settings, build-rules

I cannot find Add Custom Build Rule option on Version 5.0 (5A1413). Does anyone noticed it? Has it been moved somewhere else?

As a work around I am clicking "Copy to Target" on any build rule and customising it to make it custom build!!!

[ANSWER]

Build Rules -> Custom then select Editor->Add Build Rule

[image: Editor greyed out]

Comment: The answer is in the menu in your screenshot. Choose Editor > Add Build Rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the build file selected, open the `Editor` menu.

This is also where the `Add User-Defined Build Setting` and other build setting modifications were moved to.

Comment: I tried that. Please see edited question image and work around.

Answer (score 0):

Are *Build Phases* what you're looking for?

As a new developer in the Mac world, here's where I found it:

`Open Project Navigator -> click the top item (i.e. the project item)` in there.

An editor opens up with multiple tabs: `General, Capabilities, Info, Build Settings`, ***Build Phases***, and ***Build Rules***.

Then I added a new `Run Script`-rule and dragged it in proper place to be executed at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

**Checked on XCode 9:**

Select *Project's Target file* -> Select "*Editor*" in top menu -> Select "*Add Build Settings*" -> Then Select "*Add User-Defined Settings*"

**Important**: If '*Add User-Defined Settings*' is grayed out. Then select "*Build Settings*" from Project Setting Tabs.

See below screenshot

[image]