# Xcode compile error: Command Lex failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am getting an error message in Xcode for an iOS project during compile time pertaining to the file 6844.lm in my project that says:

> Command Lex failed with a nonzero exit code

What is Xcode trying to do here with command Lex? The .lm file isn't even inteded by me to be compiled by Xcode. It needs to be used by a third party framework. Is there a way for me to tell Xcode not to try to perform that Lex command that is generating an error?

I don't show my code because the error apparently occurs before the compiler gets to my code.

I have done a Clean Build Folder, closed Xcode, deleted .../Xcode/DerivedData folder, opened the project again, and build the project again.

I have tried putting the filenames in Target->Build Settings->Build Options->Excluded Source File Names. That excluded the files from compiling, but apparently those files aren't copied into the app at all, so when I try to access the files using Bundle.path(forResource:withExtension:), I get a nil.

Here is the entire section of messages pertaining to that error message:

```
Lex /Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode\ Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm (in target: TrialTLShinxCarthage)
    cd /Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode\ Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex -o /Users/shinehah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrialTLShinxCarthage-aahrnoeujgjtocdrubugzphgavxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/TrialTLShinxCarthage.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TrialTLShinxCarthage.build/DerivedSources/6844.yy.m /Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode\ Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm

/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:6: name defined twice
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:9: name defined twice
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:12: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:12: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:12: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:12: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:14: name defined twice
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:15: name defined twice
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:17: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:17: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:17: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:17: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:17: bad character: :
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: /
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:18: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 2
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:19: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 2
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:20: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 2
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:21: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 2
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 5
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:22: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:24: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:24: bad character: 2
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:24: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:24: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:24: bad character: :
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:25: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:26: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:27: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: /
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:28: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:30: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:30: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:30: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:30: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:30: bad character: :
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:31: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: <
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: /
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:32: bad character: >
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: -
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: .
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: 3
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: bad character: 0
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:33: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:35: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:35: unknown error processing section 1
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:35: bad character: \
/Users/shinehah/Documents/Xcode Projects/Trials/TrialTLShinxCarthage/TrialTLShinxCarthage/6844.lm:36: premature EOF
Command Lex failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Did you tried clean your project and build it again? Cmd+Shift+K for Clean and after that Cmd+B

Comment: @Dris Yes. I also closed Xcode completely after doing the Clean and moved the DerivedData folder in the Xcode folder to the trash. Then opened the project again and build again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling some files in Xcode project from compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600762/disabling-some-files-in-xcode-project-from-compilation)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev A got a good answer from that duplicate to exlude the files generating the error inTarget->Build Settings->Build Options->Excluded Source File Names, but then those files can't be found using Bundle.path(...).