# Prevent classes from compiling on specific iOS version

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlsession

I have a class that is using `NSURLSession` and I still need to support iOS 6.
When I try to compile targeting iOS 6, it fails, since `NSURLSession` doesn't exist.

How do i disable this class from compiling for iOS 6?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could check current version and split your code accordingly... Like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848766/how-can-we-programmatically-detect-which-ios-version-is-device-running-on

Comment: i can use the check   `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000` which will only compile on IOS7, but its not very pretty since it needs to be over the whole file

Comment: Yanchi's suggestion is good for when you don't want an application to crash due to unrecognized selectors, etc, when running on a device. If you just want to ignore a file so that Xcode 4 will allow you to compile the rest, remove it from the target, as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561715/xcode-is-there-a-location-flag-to-prevent-a-class-from-compiling

Comment: The issue is targeting iOS 6, not the XCode version.

Comment: If you create a second target for iOS 6, and remove your incompatible classes from it, you should be able to choose between building for an iOS 6 target and an iOS 7 target.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support both iOS 7 and iOS 6.x then your base sdk should be iOS7 and iOS Deployment target should be iOS 6.0.

You should be modifying your class so that your application supports both iOS 7 and iOS 6.x

```
if ([NSURLSession class]) {
    // Use NSURLSession
}
else {
    // Start background task, iOS 6 way
}
```

Comment: Mostly people just set the "Base SDK" to "iOS Latest" these days, but otherwise agree.