# Unit Testing in xcode5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, unit-testing

I've been asked to debug a prototype iPad app (written in Objective C). I thought a good approach would be to write a series of unit tests (IDing bugs and helping me familiarise myself with the code). Though I have written unit tests before I've never used xcode, Objective C; or a Mac for that matter.

The problem being that the code as it stands won't currently build - there are a large number of errors. I'm wondering if there is a way to unit test certain parts of the code using xcode without having to build the entire project; or do I need to ID what's causing all or the errors and eliminate these first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on how deeply linked the components are, if the error producing components are separate enough (i.e they only communicate/are used by themselves), then you could simply remove [them from the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561715/xcode-is-there-a-location-flag-to-prevent-a-class-from-compiling).

However, if the components are also necessary for the remainder of the app (the parts you want to test), then you would need to fix the errors first, as otherwise you couldn't really test the full functionality in your unit tests.